# Javascript only working once (not even a second time after page refresh) in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

First question on SO...please forgive me if it's poorly done.

This appears to be a normally discussed problem (a search yields dozens if not hundreds of posts "my JS only works on page refresh" all solved by using `jquery-turbolinks` and adding it to `application.js`).

I've taken all those steps. However I'm experiencing something that almost no one else references...

The problem:

- My Javascript does work only once (like everyone mentions), but then
  it never works again, even after a page refresh.
- I AM able to
  successfully get it to work a second time...if I make a change to the
  page source file and then save it. Then the next time I visit that
  page the Javascript will work...once.

Here's what we've got:

This adds the `localScroll` animation to the div I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('page:load', ready)
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#nav').localScroll({duration:800});
    });
</script>
```

The JS libraries I'm using (links broken since I'm a newb and can only include up to two links in a post...):

- github. com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo
- github. com/flesler/jquery.localScroll

Both are downloaded and added to `app/assets/javascripts`

[image: link to a screenshot since I'm a newb and can't embed it...]

Both are required in `application.js` (the last two before `//= require_tree .`).

I've installed and added `jquery-turbolinks` to my `gemfile`, run Bundler, required it in `application.js` (before `turbolinks` but after `jquery`), and stopped/started the rails server.

I didn't add all the details around the div and name/href combinations I'm using since the animation does does work once. I'm assuming my problem is very closely related to what everyone else experiences, but I just can't find a solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

UPDATE

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The localScroll.js and scrollTo.js is in the javascripts folder so `require_tree .` does grab them (I inspected the page after it loaded to verify).

This pops the alert every time **any** page in the application is loaded **after** the page with the function has been called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        alert("JQuery is working!");
        $('#nav').localScroll({duration:800});
    });

</script>
```

Then it pops the alert twice on any new page if I load the page with the function again. Then three times if I load it again...I'm assuming that something under the hood is interfering with with this JS which is why the `.localScroll` call itself isn't working...

UPDATE 2
Alternate solution

I ended up abandoning trying to work with localScroll and scrollTo and instead just used this agnostic internal link interceptor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("a[href^=#]").click(function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault(); 

                var dest = $(this).attr('href'); 
                console.log(dest); 

                $('html,body').animate(
                    { scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top }, 'slow'
                ); 

                history.pushState(null, null, dest);
            });
        }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling ready on page load, but seem to be missing the ready function.

Try the following snippet:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
   $('#nav').localScroll({duration:800});
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Your answer is fine now, np for the feedback leading to the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you - doesn't surprise me that I missed something like that. Unfortunately, the problem is persisting, though now the scroll animation will not fire even if I edit the page. Let me know if you need any additional info. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you add a console.log or alert, in the ready function to see if it gets called at all ?

Comment: Update...apparently it does still work only once if I edit the file. Also, I added an alert to the body of the ready function and apparently it's stacking up somehow, if I go to the previous view and back into this one it adds an extra alert window each time but I use the original JS I had it only pops once, so I think the function is called.

Comment: Just added another update with a totally different approach. Would still love to learn why the libraries weren't working, but for now the practical problem is solved.